How to extract incoming data from a http rest request in a service in Moqui?
I want to extract json data from incoming request in a Moqui Service
I have created a service in Moqui which processes incoming data, the problem is data comes as a direct json insted of being nested into one parent object. Ex
{
    "key": "value",
    "key2": "value",
    "key3": "value"
}

If it was something like this -
{
"parent":{
    "key": "value",
    "key2": "value",
    "key3": "value"
}
}

I could define one service parameter called parent and use it to get the data
I have tried creating mutiple serivce input parameters to get that data in my service but the incoming request can have numerous keys, I don't want to define so many input parameters in my service. Does anyone know a way to extract the whole request body as it is ?
